# After forced login, return to first entered login

Tags: users

I have situation where i redirect user programatically on condition. After condition is met:

```
drupal_goto('http://www.mydomain.com/user/login');
```

But what it does, it forgets path that was initially entered by user.

Is there a way to redirect user to login (programatically), but to remember url ?
(as it works when you try to login to admin area).

BTW, i have Login Tobbogan also installed. (Drupal 7)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take you want to redirect the user from the login page to the page where you are checking the condition. If this is the case, the code you should use is the following one.

```
drupal_goto('user/login', array('query' => array('destination' => $GET['q'])));
```

Otherwise, if you want to redirect the users to the destination set from other modules, when there is one, or the current page, then the code should be similar to the following one.

```
drupal_goto('user/login', array('query' => drupal_get_destination()));
```

Remember that the first two parameters accepted from `drupal_goto()` are the same parameters accepted from [url()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/url/7).

Comment: Second approach solves what i needed: q parameter is appended on login, and after login, im redirected to url. Only, the ugly query is visible on login page. Could it be masked, withouth query, or with clean urls ? (not?)

Comment: This answer is actually the same as mine, but I missed out the query parameter. A green tick swiped from under my feet.

Comment: With clean URLs, the `?q=[…]` part would not be visible, but the `redirect=[…]` part would still be visible, also because Drupal looks for `$_GET['redirect']`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the correct way to do this is:

```
drupal_goto('user/login', array('query' => drupal_get_destination()));
```

The documentation for [drupal_get_destination()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_get_destination/7) states:

> Prepares a 'destination' URL query parameter for use with drupal_goto().
>
> Used to direct the user back to the referring page after completing a form. By default the current URL is returned. If a destination exists in the previous request, that destination is returned. As such, a destination can persist across multiple pages.

Update: You could try putting the URL in directly:

```
$path = 'path-to-redirect-to'; // or $GET['q']
drupal_goto('user/login', 'query' => array('destination' => $path)));
```

Comment: tried, but not redirected after login where initial link was leading... are you sure this is the way ? :) Because if it is, i have another thingy which lands me on user profile page... thanks!

Comment: There is no redirect going on in your form? Do you see the ?destination=* part of the URL at the login form? I've updated the answer.

Comment: interesting approach for further reference! But this solves problem for me: drupal_goto('user/login', array('query' => drupal_get_destination()));